# LDAP Password too young to change

Tags: ldap

I have a user that cannot change their password so I am trying to do it manually. When I try to change it, I am getting the following error message:

```
ldap_modify: Constraint violation (19)
        additional info: Password is too young to change
```

I created an ldif file for the user in my home directory:

```
dn: where this user is located
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: thenewpassword

add: pwdReset
pwdReset: TRUE
```

I am executing the ldif file like this:

```
sudo ldapmodify -D 'uid=*****' -W -f ****.ldif
```

I am at a loss here guys, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in that command your trying to do that as the user not the admin group user

do it like this

```
ldapmodify -D "cn=admin,dc=imageek,dc=yesyouare" -W -x -f huehuehue.ldif
```

-x for *unencrypted* i don't know what your using ssl or tls so use it like this it will ask for ldap admin user password in opensure or redhat the admin user that has write access to the **DIT** is called **manager**.

and edit the ldif file like this

```
dn: uid=onepunchman,dc=imageek,dc=yesyouare
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: newpunchword_bwahaha
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thanks for answering so quickly!!!

Comment: Being a hidden leaf village ninja is convenient in a time like this